# Не компилируется программа

Tags: классы, visual-c++, указатели, структуры

Нужно создать статический указатель на структуру внутри класса и инициализировать его статической функцией. При попытке компиляции выдаёт ошибку :

Ошибка  LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ ""private: static struct B * MyClass::pin" (?pin@MyClass@@0PAUB@@A)"

код:

```
struct B {
    int c;
};

class MyClass {
    static B*pin;
public:
    static void set(int i) { 
        pin = new B;
        pin->c = i;
    }
};
B MyClass::*pin;
int main() {
    MyClass a;
    MyClass::set(10);
    return 0;
}
```

В чём проблема, как исправить? Компилятор MSVS 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис определения для вашего `MyClass::pin`

```
B *MyClass::pin;
```

У вас же объявляется внешняя переменная `pin` типа `B MyClass::*`, не имеющая никакого отношения к `MyClass::pin`. Поле `MyClass::pin` остается не определенным, вследствие чего и возникает ошибка линковки.